# Counting items in a column using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I am trying to write an SQL query that will add the number of times an email address is in the sender column and recipient column in the table Transactions.

SO..

```
Sender     |  Receipient
xyz.com    |  abc.com
xyz.com    |  xyz.com
sdz.com    |  abc.com
xyz.com    |  bac.com
```

Request output:

```
Email address  |  Sent  |  Received
xyz.com           3           1
sdz.com           1           0
abc.com           0           2
bac.com           0           1
```

What I  have so far:

```
SELECT Sender, COUNT(Sender) as 'Total Sent', COUNT(recipient) as 'Total 
Received'
FROM Transactions (NOLOCK)
group by Sender
order by sender
```

THANK YOU for any assistance!

Comment: If you are going to use table hints the with keyword being omitted is deprecated. Of course, the NOLOCK hint a slippery slope that many people don't fully understand. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 2):

Since you are making 2 distinct groupings, i recommend to self-join, like:

```
SELECT a.Sender, COUNT(a.Sender) AS 'Total Sent',  b.recieved AS 'Total 
Received'
FROM Transactions
JOIN (SELECT Receipient, COUNT(Receipient) AS recieved 
      FROM Transactions
      GROUP BY b.Receipient) b ON b.Receipient=a.Sender
GROUP BY a.Sender
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `union all` and aggregation.

```
select email_address
,count(case when type='Sent' then 1 end) as sent
,count(case when type='Received' then 1 end) as received
from (SELECT Sender as email_address,'Sent' as type
      FROM Transactions 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT Receiver,'Received'
      FROM Transactions 
     ) t
group by email_address
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sum on case when and union all for get  the email

```
    select Email_address 
        , sum(case when  t_type = 'Sender', then 1 else 0 end) sent
        , sum(case when  t_type = 'Receipient', then 1 else 0 end) Receipient
    from (
        select 'Sender' t_type,   Sender as sent
        from Transactions
        union All
        select 'Receipient' t_type,  Recipient
        from Transactions ) t
    group by Email_address
```